# Calculate expiry date based on another column which is AccountType

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a problem when I want to add a new column which is ExpireDate to my table (Player_Table) and calculate its value automatically based on the AccountType column, here is my scenario:

I have RegisteredDate(data type: date-time) column and AccountType(data type: nvchar(50)) for Example AccountType is equals to "3 Months" and I want to calculate  ExpireDate by multiplying RigisteredDate by 3 I think it may work but I don't know how to calculate exactly.

| id | Name | PlayerGender | PlayerAge | phone | RegisteredDate | AccountType | ExpireDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | nahro | male | 20 | 00000 | 2021/3/5 | 3 months | ?? |
| 2 | poshya | female | 21 | 7858 | 2021/3/15 | 6 months | ?? |

And also how to implement this in C# Winform when I want to count the expired players.

Comment: What does it mean to multiply a date-time by a number?

Comment: Typically AccountType would be a separate table linked by a foreign key because you generally need to store a few things about an account type.

Answer (score 0):

Add a column to numerically store the duration until account expires

```
alter table Player_Table add Duration int not null default(3)
```

The `ExpireDate` column can then become a computed column

```
alter table Player_Table add column Expire_Date as
dateadd(mm,Duration,RegisteredDate)
```

Alternatively, or in addition to, you could add and `Expired` column and similarly use a `computed column` with `case` to display **1** if the account has expired, you can then count or sum this column.

Comment: Hello Dear, I don't understand default(3).

Comment: @NahroAso please check out the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @NahroAso - the default value for new rows - I chose 3 based on your sample data, the value is arbitrary.